Would rememberance of past lives by a spiritual method checked by lie detector test be considered strong evidence of reincarnation in neuroscience?

(16) Knowledge of the past and the future can be derived through
saṃyama on the three pariṇāmas (changes). (17) Overlapping of word,
object implied and the idea there of produces one unified impression.
If saṃyama is practised on each separately, knowledge of the meaning of the sound produced by all beings can be acquired. (18) By
the realization of latent impressions, knowledge of previous birth is
acquired.
Source: Yog sutra Chapter 3
By the constant recitation of the Veda, by purification, by austerity,
and by doing no harm to living beings, he remembers his previous
birth.—(148)
Source: Manusmriti Ch 4 v. 148

Whether you believe in rebirth or not, please answer my question in terms of neuroscience.
Would rememberance of past lives by a spiritual method (as mentioned above) checked by a lie detector test be considered strong evidence of reincarnation in neuroscience?
Also, what limitations are there in neuroscience to considering them evidence? Please explain in detail.

Welcome Small Kid. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [ask] section of the [help]. You ask about lie-detectors, what has your research into their reliability or trustworthiness revealed and where did you get stuck? Could you [edit] to tell us. There's this other question. Then there's issues relating to self deception and biased reporting of experiences where the person believes what they say - you can look into that.
